# Call constructor in if condition as a part of the comma expression?

Tags: c++, if-statement, constructor

Here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


struct Sales_data {
    Sales_data() = default;

    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    if (Sales_data item, a)
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

I don't know why the compiler tell me expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool).

Comment: Are you trying to have a variable called `item` scoped to the `if` statement?

Comment: Because `if` statement has wrong syntax. What you are trying to achieve, compare `item` against `a`?

Comment: The compiler expects something convertible to bool, because it needs to know how to determine whether to branch.

Comment: I just define the variable item and initialize it in the if condition.

Comment: And that's just not valid C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not a valid if-statement. It's not a valid statement of any kind, in any context.  This is also invalid:

```
bool a;
Sales_data item, a;   // what does this mean?!
```

And this is invalid:

```
bool a;
bool b = Sales_data item, a;  // ???
```

In C++17 you can do what you want, but using different syntax:

```
if (Sales_data item; a)
  ...
```

This is analogous to the initializer in a `for` statement:

```
for (Sales_item item; expr; expr)
  ...
```

Statements must be separated by `;` not commas.

Comment: But when I call another constructor of class Sales_item such as Sales_data item(cin) instead of Sales_data item, I also get a error.

Comment: Yes, because that's also nonsense. Why do you say "but"? Nothing in my answer suggests it would behave otherwise. Try doing that in the other contexts I show and it also fails: `Sales_data item(cin), a;` or `bool b = Sales_data item(cin), a;`. You can't declare a variable as part of an expression that is not a variable declaration. You simply can't compile code that isn't valid C++.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not a valid syntax. It is interpreted as a declaration of two variables (so `,` is not the comma operator here), which you cannot have inside an if condition.

What you are trying will be possible in C++17 with the following syntax:

```
if (Sales_data item; a)
```

until then, if you want a variable to be scoped to the if you can do:

```
if (a)
{
  Sales_data item;
  ...
}
```

Or, if you need the variable inside the condition you could create an enclosing scope:

```
{
Sales_data item;
if (item == ...)
{
   ...
}
} // item is destructed here
```

Comment: But when I call another constructor of class Sales_item such as Sales_data item(cin) instead of Sales_data item, I also get a error. Can this be  interpreted as a declaration of two variables?

Comment: @K.Robert do you have a constructor that accepts an object `cin`?

Comment: Yes, and it can be called correctly outside the if condition.

Comment: well, the if condition needs to evaluate to `bool` so that you know if you take the branch or not. An `Sales_data` object is not convertible to bool.